# How to find the GoogleMap GeoLocation User Request Limits and Business Request Limit ? Pricing of Business Rquest?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, salesforce, google-geolocation

I am using GoogleMap GeoLocation for find the distance between two address in salesforce. but GoogleMap GeoLocation only provide 2500 for user request(per day-24 hr). if we want more its provide upto 1,00,000 Request. i need the pricing for this licence and details about the GeoLocation . i didnt get the exact licence amount. any one help out this. thanks for your advance

Answer (score 0):

Read [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/).

Get an API key, and use it in your API calls. Then you can see your realtime usage within the [APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect), and pricing is available in there also.

Comment: Already i used the GeoLocation but i am using user request only. i want maps for business request. so need the pricing of this business limits.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off asking Google for pricing, as per their page describes?  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#usage_limits

Comment: GeoLocation and GeoCode both are different purpose?

Comment: Two completely different things. Geolocation = "The Google Maps Geolocation API returns a location and accuracy radius based on information about cell towers and WiFi nodes that the mobile client can detect."  Geocoding = "Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers or position the map. Reverse geocoding is the process of converting geographic coordinates into a human-readable address."

Comment: Great! got it now. but now i want premium amount for businees map in geocode. Can you help out this. no one link not provide exact pricing

Comment: No they dont mention it anywhere - i guess you have to contact them because the pricing may vary per region and your usage requirements etc.

Comment: this is the only way.are you sure . we must call only get the price?

Comment: can you find the prices listed anywhere?  i can't.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/usagelimits/?utm_referrer=v3 
This link for common all the google api pricing?